# CSS Transform (rotate) misbehaving

Tags: css, transform

I'm not having much luck with what I thought would be a very simple change but that's life I guess :)

I just wanted 1 div with several divs inside beside each other that contained some vertical text.  This fiddle probably explains it best -> http://jsfiddle.net/urbley/pq6fuyeL/

```
CSS
.side-dates {
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.side-date {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 76% 76%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 70px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

HTML
<div class="side-dates">
    <div class="side-date">this is a test1</div>
    <div class="side-date">this is a test2</div>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm getting some nasty margins left and right of the individual vertical divs.  Does anyone have any idea where they are coming from/how to fix?

Comment: I believe the rotation is only a visual effect. So the elements are still taking up the space of their original place and size on the page (before the rotation).

Comment: can you change your html? http://jsfiddle.net/pq6fuyeL/2/

Comment: Thanks Danko.  Works a treat!  Put it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `transform` is taken from the actual position and doesn't change that. So the elements are rotated but doesn't `float` as you expect. So if you can change your markup you can try `rotate` an inner element:

```
<div class="side-dates">
  <div class="side-date">
      <span>this is a test1</span>
  </div>
```

And with CSS:

```
.side-date {
    height: 70px;
    width: 20px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.side-date span {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:100%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 70px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Check this **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pq6fuyeL/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

It's according to the specs See what the spec says:

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, the
>   transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding
>   the transformed element. However, the extent of the overflow area
>   takes into account transformed elements. This behavior is similar to
>   what happens when elements are offset via relative positioning.
>   Therefore, if the value of the overflow property is scroll or auto,
>   scrollbars will appear as needed to see content that is transformed
>   outside the visible area.
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering

If you want them to stack with their "new dimensions" you'll have to do something else, like using a wrapper for each div like this:

```
.side-date-wrapper
{
    width: 21px;
    height: 72px;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pq6fuyeL/6/

Answer (score 0):

Like myfunkyside mentioned, the css here is only visual effect, and the originals are still taking up space. See below for solution

```css
.side-dates {
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.side-date-outter {
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 76% 76%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -2px;
    top: 39px;
    width: 16px;
}

.side-date {
    height: 14px;
    width: 64px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
    top: 1px;    
}
```

```html
    <div class="side-dates">
        <div class="side-date-outter">
            <div class="side-date">this is a test1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="side-date-outter">
            <div class="side-date">this is a test2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```